# my BDD step_impl(context) get called two times, Why? I expected it triggers only once

Tags: bdd

x.feature file:

```
  Scenario Outline: Open Solution Drop-Down Mneu
    Given a table
      | menu     |
      | Products2 |
      | Services2 |
      | Sales2    |
```

x.py

```py
@Given ("a table")
def step_impl(context):
  for row in context.table:
    print(f'0000 {row["menu"]}')
```

Output:

```
0000 Products2
0000 Services2
0000 Sales2

0000 Products2
0000 Services2
0000 Sales2
```

I expect the `step_impl()` get called only once.